Why is it imposible call a Length method on Tuple or ValueTuple instanses
When I try to call Length method it does not exist on 'Tuple' instanse
    Tuple<int, string> tuple = Tuple.Create(1, "1");
    var l = tuple.Length;

And i receive default error like this "Error    CS1061  'Tuple<int, string, int, int, char>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'Tuple<int, string, int, int, char>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
But Tuple implement interface ITuple from System.Runtime.CompilerServices that contains Lenth method
In addition if I do explicit cast to ITuple method exist
      Tuple<int, string> tuple = Tuple.Create(1, "1");
      var l = ((ITuple)tuple).Length;


I haven't looked but, presumably, that's because Tuple and ValueTuple implement ITuple.Length explicitly; i.e., you must cast to the ITuple to access the property. Have a look at explicit interface implementation.

The documentation of ITuple is specific about this:

ITuple is an explicit interface implementation of the Tuple classes and the ValueTuple structures. You must cast the Tuple object to an ITuple interface object before you can access its properties.


you are right, Tuple and ValueTuple explicit implement ITuple, and ITupleInternal. For the reason that visual studio decompiler does not show that Tuple implement internal interfaces I didn't think about explicit implementation. Thanks
